# Bipartite in NetworkX not working properly when renaming nodes

Tags: python, networkx, bipartite

I am trying to convert a bipartite graph to a person-to-person graph using networkX:

```
import networkx as nx
import ast
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite
x=(161,1),(589,2),(162,1),(163,1),(589,2)
BI = nx.Graph()
BI.add_edges_from(x)
bottom_nodes, top_nodes = bipartite.sets(BI)
GI = bipartite.projected_graph(BI, top_nodes)
GI.edges()
```

The result is not correct:

```
>>> bottom_nodes
{161, 162, 163, 2}
>>> top_nodes
{1, 589}
```

If I change x to be:

```
x=(61,1),(58,2),(62,1),(63,1),(59,2)
```

The I get correct result:

```
>>> bottom_nodes
{1, 2}
>>> top_nodes
{58, 59, 61, 62, 63}
```

So somehow if I use "lower" numbers for nodes, then the conversion is correct, otherwise not. But, I need bigger numbers since I have more than 100 nodes.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102592/choosing-which-sets-of-nodes-are-top-and-bottom-in-bipartite-graph-represent

Comment: As a side note, you can write `BI = nx.Graph(x)` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node sets in a bipartite graphs are equivalent (correct me if I'm using a wrong term) - there's no principal difference which to name "top" and which "bottom".

As per the references in [Choosing which sets of nodes are 'top' and 'bottom' in bipartite graph representations of real-world complex networks. - Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102592/choosing-which-sets-of-nodes-are-top-and-bottom-in-bipartite-graph-represent), classifying them as such is a matter of convention (for uniformity) agreed upon in specific applications rather than any mathematical differences. So, both answers are actually correct.

Looking at the source code of `networkx.algorithms.bipartite.sets` shows that it delegates to `networkx.algorithms.bipartite.color` which, in turn, iterates over the nodes. The node that comes first in `for n in G` is always assigned color `1` and gets into the first set in `sets`:

```
In [2]: x=(161,1),(589,2),(162,1),(163,1),(589,2)
In [4]: g=networkx.Graph(x)
In [8]: g2=networkx.Graph(((80,2),(589,2),(162,1),(163,1),(589,2)))

In [11]: [n for n in g]
Out[11]: [161, 2, 163, 1, 162, 589]

In [12]: [n for n in g2]
Out[12]: [1, 2, 163, 162, 589, 80]

In [14]: networkx.algorithms.bipartite.sets(g)
Out[14]: ({2, 161, 162, 163}, {1, 589})

In [13]: networkx.algorithms.bipartite.sets(g2)
Out[13]: ({1, 2}, {80, 162, 163, 589})
```

So, if you have some specific idea which *unrelated* properties of a node should classify it as "top"/"bottom", you need to *actually program it in:* e.g. look at the result and see what got where.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already know what your bipartite sets are you can specify them explicitly.

```
import networkx as nx                                                           
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite                                       
x=(161,1),(589,2),(162,1),(163,1),(589,2)                                       
BI = nx.Graph(x)                                                                
top = set(s for s,t in x)                                                       
print(top)                                                                      
GI = bipartite.projected_graph(BI, top)                                         
print(list(GI.edges()))
```

OUTPUT

```
set([161, 162, 163, 589])
[(161, 162), (161, 163), (162, 163)]
```